# If $f'(c)=0$ then is it necessary that $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

From Rolle's theorem we know that if a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be such that

1. $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$,
2. $f$ is differentiable at every point of $(a,b)$,
3. $f(a)=f(b)$,

then there exist at least one point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. 
Now my question is if $f'(c)=0$ for some c in $(a,b)$ then is it necessary that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$? If not how can I prove that? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are asking: if a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is such that it is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and for some $c\in (a,b)$ holds that $f'(c)=0$, is it then the case that $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$. The answer is no, as the following counter examples shows. Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x)=0$ if $x\in (0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=1$. It is clear $f$ is not continuous in $[a,b]$ but satisfies the other conditions.

Note, that $f$ must be continuous on $(a,b)$ since differentiability at a point implies continuity at the same point.

Answer (score 3):

For $f$ to be differentiable at some point $c$ it has to be continuous there. Continuity at one point $c$ does not imply continuity on the interval $[a,b]$.